# I have some Concepts and these Concepts have Concept Sub. All of these insert together

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have some Concepts and these Concepts have Concept Sub.

All  of these insert together.

Now I Want To Update these. **For Example**: *Concept-1* has three sub as *conceptSub-1, conceptSub-2, conceptSub-3*.

I want To ***Update*** this (add or delete one of their Sub).

ConceptDto:

```
public Guid ConceptManagementId { get; set; }

public string ConceptName { get; set; }

public bool IsOriginalNameShow { get; set; }

public bool IsSubNameShow { get; set; }

public List<ConceptSubDto> ConceptSubSidiary { get; set; }
```

ConceptSubDto:

```
public Guid ConceptSubId { get; set; }

public string  ConceptSubName { get; set; }
```

This is myService:

```
  public async Task<bool> UpdateConcept(ConceptManagementDto dto)
        {
            var concept = await _conceptManagementRepository.Query().Include(x => x.conceptSubSidiaries)
                .GetOneAsync(x => x.Id == dto.ConceptManagementId);

            concept.EditConcept(dto.ConceptName,
                dto.IsSubNameShow,
                dto.IsOriginalName
            );


         ?
         ?
                   
        _conceptManagementRepository.Update(concept);
        await _conceptManagementRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
```

Please can you help me figure out what is missing where I placed the question marks?